# Pass a webform value to a node via Rules?

Tags: webforms, rules

I have a rule that is successfully creating a node of a content type when a webform is submitted. How do I pass a value from the webform into the created node via rules? (This is a Drupal 7 site.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Hidden inputs in webform.
2. Assign to this hidden inputs values (prepopulated in url, tokens, webform rules or programmatically).
3. Assign these inputs to content fields using Rules.